# Freezing due to lack of ram?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Problem: Made a huge nested list with over 500k combinations. When loading or running terminal and visual studio the laptop freezes. I just upgraded ram from 4gb(2×2) to 8gb(1×8). I am planning to add another 8gb stick. 
Cpu: i5-2520m
Question:  Is it lack of ram or processor that might bee causing the laptop to freeze. 
Note: I use a cooling pad.

Comment: Python alone isn't designed to work with big data.

Comment: Could you explain more about what's in the list? If by list of combinations you mean you're pregenerating all possible combinations of two sets, you can do that in a much better way.

Comment: You could try creating a generator instead of a list, and then either use that generator to process the data, or use the generator to output the data to a database where you can quickly and efficiently perform queries on the data.

Comment: @COLDSPEED- Thanks. Just learning.

Comment: @Gricery- Thanks. Just learning. That's the frustrating part. I'm trying to do something I'm not ready for.

Comment: @Mr. Me- I will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds to me that you have a file with a bunch of data that really should be a database.

please consider using a database instead of a file to represent the 500,000 records nested list.

this will have the effect of increasing the performance of your current set up and also will allow you to execute complex queries and indexing into the data.
if you don't feel like networking and all that jazz I also recommend that you use SQLITE.

SQLITE has C and C++ bindings that allow you to easily use it from python among other languages and also is very efficient.

Comment: Thank you Felipe Valdes. I will try all your solutions: @Gricey, @ Mr. Me

Comment: very well, I'm happy I was of assistance :D